# Can a square be equal to three times a square in $\mathbb{N}^*$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have this equation:
    $$m^2 = 3n^2$$
So from equation above I can say that $m^2$ can be divided by $3$, that is $m$ is divided by $3$ as well - as this is said in the text book.

But it's not clear for me why $m$ is divided by $3$???

Comment: Remark that $3$ is a prime number.

Comment: Consider the prime factorization of $m^2$.

Comment: Have you realized that your issue is equivalent to $\dfrac{m}{n}=\pm\sqrt{3}$ ? Do you think it is possible that the square root of $3$ is a rational number ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Well, his equation arises in a standard proof that $\sqrt{3}$ is an irrational number...

Comment: @Guest Is it so certain ?

Comment: I propose a title which is ... a title (important for further queries).You may not agree...

Comment: "Can a square be equal to three times a square?" Yes.  $0^2 = 3\cdot 0^2$.

Comment: @JeanMarie To prove that $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational, suppose that it is rational, say $\sqrt{3}=m/n$ for integers $m$ and $n$ such that $(m,n)=1$ and $n\neq0$. Then we'll have $m^2=3n^2$. The contradiction you eventually seek is that $(m,n)\neq1$ and you would do this by showing that $3|m$ and $3|n$. This is probably where the OP gets his question from, and I suspect that in his textbook the author said, after $m^2=3n^2$, that we infer $3|m^2$ and so $3|m$ (without further explanations). The answer addresses this in more detail, basically saying that $m=3q+r$ with $r\in\{1,2\}$ is impossible.

Comment: @Guest I agree.

Comment: @Daniel McLaury Of course, I cannot say you are wrong (I have added a $\mathbb{N}^*$) but consider that the previous title was not at all related to the question.

Answer (score 2):

If the product of two numbers is a multiple of $3$, then one of them (at least) is a multiple of three. This follows, as commented on your question, from the fact that $3$ is prime - but if you want an even more elementary way to check it, it suffices to remark that $(3k+1)\times(3k'+1)$, $(3k+1)\times(3k'+2)$, and $(3k+2)\times(3k'+2)$ are not multiple of three. To exemplify this with the first product, $(3k+1)\times(3k'+1) = 3(3kk' + k + k') + 1 = 3K + 1$ for an integer $K$. Therefore, no product of non-multiple of three is a multiple of three.

In the case of $m^2 = 3n^2$, then this directly implies that $3$ divides $m$.

Answer (score 0):

If $m$ wasn't divisible by $3$ then, by [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division), we would have $m=3q+r$ with $r\in\{1,2\}$. But then we would have $m^2=3(3q^2+2r)+r^2$ and $3\nmid r^2$, contradicting the fact that $m^2$ is divisible by $3$.